# Filtering view in lotus notes

Tags: lotus-notes, lotus-domino, lotus, lotusscript, lotus-formula

good day,

I'm trying to filter date by year using `@setviewinfo`. can anyone tell me how?

Comment: What have you already tried? Please add some more info. For info: here's the online help: http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/domhelp/v8r0/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.ibm.designer.domino.main.doc%2FH_EXAMPLES_SETVIEWINFO_EX.html

Comment: all i tried, i get error and no value.

Answer (score 3):

Here is an example, put this formula on PostOpen event on view. It will filter all document by column with user name.

```
@SetViewInfo([SetViewFilter]; @UserName; "columnName"; 1; 1)
```

columnName - is a real name of column (you may set it in Column Property)

Remember to clean filter on QueryClose even on view, otherwise all view will use this filter.

example how u should remove filter

```
@SetTargetFrame("frameName");
@UpdateFormulaContext;
@Command([OpenView]; @Subset(@ViewTitle; -1));
@SetViewInfo([SetViewFilter]; ""; "columnName"; 1)
```

frameName is a frame that contains view, columnName is your categorized column. If you do not use frame - simply skip 1-st row

Comment: If you use a check box (or a combo box) select the "refresh fields on keyword change" and put the above code into the Postrecalc event (which can be changed to use formula language.)